# How to add svg image to mxgraph workfloweditor example

Tags: xml, svg, mxgraph

I am using workfloweditor example of mxgraph. in this i am able to add shapes to toolbar and drag and drop from it onto the canvas but the images are in png format. instead of png i want svg image.
below is the code i have used to add my png.

```
<mxEditor defaultGroup="group" defaultEdge="edge"
    helpWindowImage="images/help.gif"
    tasksWindowImage="images/tasks.gif"
    ....
    ....
    <Array as="templates">
    <add as="task">
            <Task label="Task" description="" href="">
                <mxCell vertex="1" style="symbol;image=images/task.PNG">    
                    <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="100" height="80"/>
                </mxCell>
            </Task>
        </add>
    </Array>
```

And in my toolbar i have added it as

```
<mxDefaultToolbar>
    <add as="Task" template="task" style="symbol;image=images/task.PNG" icon="images/taskgif.gif"/>
</mxDefaultToolbar>
```

But instead of png image used in the style i want to use svg image..
i have tried as follows.

```
<mxDefaultToolbar>
    <add as="Task" template="task" style="shape=image;image=data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" icon="images/taskgif.gif"/>
</mxDefaultToolbar>
```

but its doesnt show the image
i just get image icon but not the image

Answer (score 0):

1. For js part 
   You can create your own style for it.

```
const style = new Object();
style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.SHAPE_IMAGE;
style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = mxPerimeter.RectanglePerimeter;
style[mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE] = 'images/icons48/keys1.svg';
style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = '#FFFFFF';
graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle('svg1', style); // name style
```

```
const v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, '', 230, 10, 100, 100, 'svg1');
```

It works for me.
Look code with creating [own style](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/images.html).

2. For XML part

In `config/wfeditor-commons.xml` you can change current item like example(`symbol` etc) or create new own

```
<add as="symbol">
    <Symbol label="Symbol" description="" href="">
        <mxCell vertex="1" style="symbol;image=images/symbols/my.svg">      
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="32" height="32"/>
        </mxCell>
    </Symbol>
</add>
```

Comment: But i want to create and adding new style to my workflow editor example.. it is xml .. so how to create custom style in xml

Comment: @prateeknaik check again answer, and try to understand and debugging mxgraph library in your project.